# Properties of concave,two-parameter function

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, economics

I already showed that the function $\psi(\mu,\sigma)=\mathbb{E}U(X)$ is concave in $(\mu,\sigma)$, where $X$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. $U$ is a nice concave increasing function.

Now I want to prove that $\psi$ increases with $\mu$ and decreases with $\sigma$ and if all returns (Consider $X$ as a contingent claim) are jointly Gaussian , an investor maximising the expected utility of his final wealth has to choose a mean-variance efficient portfolio.

According to the first point: This is not clear to me because when you draw a concave function and take the expectation (x-axis is variance, y-axis is mean) then $\psi$ grows as $\mu$ and $\sigma$ grows.

According to the second point: I do not know what I can do here.

Comment: It would help if you provide definition of mean-variance efficient portfolio. One definition is that a portfolio is defined to be mean-variance efficient if any other portfolio with higher $\mu$ must have higher $\sigma$ and any other portfolio with lower $\sigma$ must have lower $\mu$. In that case, no investor would choose a non-mean-efficient portfolio because there is either an alternative portfolio with higher $\mu$ but not higher $\sigma$ or with lower $\sigma$ but not lower $\mu$. In either case, the investor can increase his expected utility by choosing the alternative portfolio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y$ denote a standard normal random variable then $X$ is distributed like $\mu+\sigma Y$ hence $\psi(\mu,\sigma)=E[U(\mu+\sigma Y)]$. For every $y$, the function $\mu\mapsto U(\mu+\sigma y)$ is increasing because $U$ is increasing hence the function $\mu\mapsto\psi(\mu,\sigma)$ is increasing as a barycenter of increasing functions.

Likewise, $X$ is distributed like $\mu-\sigma Y$ hence $\psi(\mu,\sigma)=\frac12E[U(\mu+\sigma Y)+U(\mu-\sigma Y)]$. For every $y$ and $\mu$, the function $\sigma\mapsto U(\mu+\sigma y)+U(\mu-\sigma y)$ is nonincreasing on $\sigma\geqslant0$ because $U$ is concave hence the function $\sigma\mapsto\psi(\mu,\sigma)$ is nonincreasing on $\sigma\geqslant0$ as a barycenter of nonincreasing functions.

The key in the second paragraph is the fact that for every convex function $u$, the function $v:x\mapsto u(x)+u(-x)$ is nondecreasing on $x\geqslant0$. Can you show this?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not understand your last paragraph. The function $u(x)=x^2$ is convex and decreasing on the negative x axis, $u(x)+u(-x)=2x^2$ is also convex and decreasing on the negative x axis.

Comment: On $x\geqslant0$.

Comment: It is clear to me that this has to be true for $x\ge 0$, it can be seen graphically. I do not sett the connection to the mean variance portfolio.